Netplan with source-based routing for multiple NICs and Gateways
I want to configure an Ubuntu VM with multiple NICs and Gateways:
ens18: 192.168.10.0/24
ens19: 192.168.20.0/24
ens20: 192.168.30.0/24

In the best case, the IPs should be provided by my DHCP server.
The VM should run a docker host with IPVlans linked to each of the NICs. So my containers get a dedicated IP in their respective subnet and I am able to segment the network.
I already tried the following configurations:
Version A:
network:
    version: 2
    renderer: networkd
    ethernets:
        ens18:
            dhcp4: true
            dhcp4-overrides:
               route-metric: 100
            routes:
            - to: default
              via: 192.168.10.254
              table: 101
            routing-policy:
            - from: 192.168.10.0/24
              table: 101
        ens19:
            dhcp4: true
            dhcp4-overrides:
                route-metric: 101
                use-routes: false
            routes:
            - to: 192.168.20.0/24
              via: 192.168.20.254
              table: 102            
            routing-policy:
            - from: 192.168.20.0/24
              table: 102
        ens20:
            dhcp4: true
            dhcp4-overrides:
                route-metric: 102
                use-routes: false
            routes:
            - to: 192.168.30.0/24
              via: 192.168.30.254
              table: 103            
            routing-policy:
            - from: 192.168.30.0/24
              table: 103

With this configuration I am able to ping all my systems within the different subnets. However, I cannot connect to NFS, use telnet or traceroute. So something strange seems to happen.
Version B:
network:
    version: 2
    renderer: networkd
    ethernets:
        ens18:
            addresses:
            - 192.168.10.200/24
            gateway4: 192.168.10.254
            routes:
            - to: default
              via: 192.168.10.254
              table: 101
            routing-policy:
            - from: 192.168.10.0/24
              table: 101
        ens19:
            addresses:
            - 192.168.20.233/24
            gateway4: 192.168.20.254
            routes:
            - to: 192.168.20.0/24
              via: 192.168.20.254
              table: 102            
            routing-policy:
            - from: 192.168.20.0/24
              table: 102
        ens20:
            addresses:
            - 192.168.30.233/24
            gateway4: 192.168.30.254
            routes:
            - to: 192.168.30.0/24
              via: 192.168.30.254
              table: 103            
            routing-policy:
            - from: 192.168.30.0/24
              table: 103

This configuration shows an error when I try to apply it: "Conflicting default route declarations for IPv4 (table: main, metric: default), first declared in ens18 but also in ens20"
What nearly works is to not use different routing tables:
network:
    version: 2
    renderer: networkd
    ethernets:
        ens18:
            dhcp4: true
            dhcp4-overrides:
               route-metric: 100
       ens19:
            dhcp4: true
            dhcp4-overrides:
                route-metric: 101
        ens20:
            dhcp4: true
            dhcp4-overrides:
                route-metric: 102

However, if I then run a docker host on the VM and use IP Vlans for my containers, I am not able to reach selected IP addresses from the containers, e.g., 192.168.10.10 - 192.168.10.20 is reachable, 192.168.10.11 is unreachable. However, 192.168.10.11 can be reached from any other VM in the network.
I have seen a large variety of different configurations in the internet, however, I am not sure how to actually set this up.
